# How to consider centre for induced electric field circle in a flux varying space?

Tags: electromagnetism

I read it in my school book that due to symmetry reasons the electric field lines formed by varying magnetic field are circular but my doubt is where the centre of that circle in space is I mean if we consider a circle of radius r and consider another similar circle with its centre somewhere on the circumference of this circle then the point where circle intersect will give two direction of electric field ?? How ?? As the electric field we obtain should already be resultant of all the fields at that point.pls help!!

Answer (score 0):

The induced electric field lines are not always circular- it depends on the actual details of the changing magnetic field. If they are circular, it's around a particular point, not circular around every point in space.

Comment: @ Chris So if we consider a square loop with changing magnetic field through it what kind of electric field lines we'll obtain??

Comment: Depends on the details. Is the field uniform inside the square and zero outside of it? Is it from a dipole? Once you have set the field that is the source, apply Maxwell's laws. Relevant question for the method: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/125910/calculate-electric-field-induced-by-a-changing-magnetic-field)