# Why is $a = \frac{Qr}{2m} \frac{dB}{dt}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, mathematics

In Gerloch's *Magnetism and Ligand-Field Analysis*, the following derivation is provided (I'm paraphrasing):

> Let the body $Q$ be a positive charge. The acceleration along a path, $\frac{dv}{dt}$, is determined by the force $QE$ along the path:
> $$m_Q\frac{dv}{dt} = QE = \frac{Qr}{2}\frac{dB}{dt}$$
> ...providing a relationship between the change in velocity and the change in magnetic field:
> $$dv = \frac{Qr}{2m_q}dB$$

This is to say that a charge $Q$ will experience an acceleration given by $\frac{Qr}{2}\frac{dB}{dt}$, if placed in a magnetic field $B$ changing as $\frac{dB}{dt}$.

I don't quite follow (although, I have only part of the book). Clearly $a = m_Q\frac{dv}{dt} = QE$, $\;$but how did we go from that to $\;$$\frac{Qr}{2}\frac{dB}{dt}$?

Comment: Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/125910/calculate-electric-field-induced-by-a-changing-magnetic-field